# Rails Association Has_One Having Pluralisation Model Name Instead of Singular and not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, has-one

I have a model called as BigbluebuttonRoom.

```
class BigbluebuttonRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :room_options, :class_name => 'BigbluebuttonRoomOptions'
```

So when I am calling room.room_options then getting no method error.

Comment: What is in the var `room`? If its nil then you get the no method error. Hard to tell without a complete error log.

Answer (score 0):

Why you named your model `BigbluebuttonRoomOptions` in plural form? It's a bad idea to break rails conventions. Model name should be in singular form, `BigbluebuttonRoomOption`. Change it and a corresponding file name.

Also, convention for `has_one` is singular form too. Should be:

```
has_one :room_option, :class_name => 'BigbluebuttonRoomOption'
```

Comment: There are cases where you might want a `has_one` with plural form, e.g. `has_one :preferences, class: 'User::Preferences'` where the single record has a column per preference. Then it becomes: `user.preferences.something_enabled?`.